# How to add a new keyboard layout to Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

I have an Ubuntu Phone and I need a keyboard layout for a language (Romanian) that's not in the list from *System Settings / Language & Text / Keyboard layouts*.

I would like to contribute with the configuration for the new layout, but I don't know where to start. What files do I need to add or adjust?

Or is there some easier way (like just installing a specific package)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a work in progress page [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KeyboardLayouts) for creating new layouts, and also there was [this](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg11252.html) thread on the ubuntu-phone mailing list.