# How to install Norwegian keyboard and spelling?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm using a bq aquaris ubuntu phone and I really need norwegian spell check and norwegian keyboard. How can I install this thinks ?

Comment: I'm told there is no Norwegian language yet.. Take a look here if you want to try your hand at adding it though: https://askubuntu.com/questions/602690/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-to-ubuntu-touch

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation pending review at https://code.launchpad.net/~ari-kroyer-online/ubuntu-keyboard/add-norwegian-layout/+merge/250814

Comment: Hei and thanks for your answer.
Where can I find an explanation that it will run on my phone?