# How do I add commands to the Ubuntu touch terminal app

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

When you first run the terminal app in Ubuntu touch you get this menu above the keyboard where you can choose between `nano`, `fns`, `cmd`, `ctr`, `scr`.

Can I add my own? Like `vi` commands or `screen` commands.

I am talking about the specific menu that the terminal app is putting at the bottom. Not the layout of the system virtual keyboard.

Look at this picture of the terminal app, it is the dial pad looking button at the left of "CRTL+R".
(https://developer.ubuntu.com/static/devportal_uploaded/c1d70a82-7441-4966-8369-2834693d2dff-cms_page_media/952/device-2015-07-06-111047.png)

Comment: See my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/602709/392342 for how to add new layouts to the terminal app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new keyboard layout to Ubuntu Touch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602690/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-to-ubuntu-touch)

Comment: @DanielChapman No this is a different problem. The (http://askubuntu.com/questions/602690/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-to-ubuntu-touch) explains how can I modify the system keyboard itself. I want to know how to add commands to that orange(red-ish) button that sits above the keyboard. This is terminal specific. look at this image (https://developer.ubuntu.com/static/devportal_uploaded/c1d70a82-7441-4966-8369-2834693d2dff-cms_page_media/952/device-2015-07-06-111047.png), it is at left of "CTRL+R" .

Comment: Sorry i used the wrong link. :-/ Take a read of this blog post https://swordfishslabs.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/json-profiles-in-ubuntu-terminal-app/